Example of Probability Spaces with Equal Measures of Intersecting Sets
So i'm studying measure theory and i'm trying to solve this exercise:
Let $(X, A, \mu)$ be a probability space.
Give, for each $t \in \left( \frac{1}{10}, \frac{2}{5} \right)$, an example of a probability space $(X, A, \mu)$ and sets $A, B, C \in A$ that satisfy the following conditions:
$$\mu(A \cap B) = \mu(A \cap C) = \mu(B \cap C) = \frac{2}{5},$$
$$\mu(A \cap B \cap C) = t.$$
I've tried to write up the whole probability space by:
$$\mu(A)+\mu(B)+\mu(C)-3(\frac{2}{5}-t)-2t+\mu(A^c\cap B^c \cap C^c)=1$$
I've isolated terms for a given $\mu(A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c)=0.5$ so that i have $\mu(A)=\mu(B)=\mu(C)=\frac{1.7-t}{3}$ with $t \in (\frac{1}{10},\frac{2}{5})$. However, i dont know how i should find a measure function and X, so that it fullfills this. I've tried the identity mapping, but that does not seem right.
